# Preventing implicit conversion in C++

Tags: c++

I ask the user for an integer input and I do not want to execute code unless it is strictly an integer.

```
int x;
if(cin >> x)
```

For instance if the user inputs a double above, the if statement will execute with implicit conversion to an integer. Instead I don't want the code to execute at all.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Read as string and fail depending on what you parse. You do realize that's what `<<` does for you right? You wanted more control... so do it.

Comment: While it's not particularly C++-ish, the stdlib [strtol](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/strtol.html) function will let you know if the conversion terminates before the end of the string.

Comment: @StevenLu Could you explain?

Comment: @StevenLu. Could you explain that a little further?

Comment: Check the behavior of what you wrote...

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Could you all explain instead of being passive aggressive about it?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I am not passive aggressive, but he is asking how to avoid what won't happen with his code. I am just suggesting that he checks the behavior of what he wrote.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas If you enter "2.3" then it puts 2 in the x and works. He doesn't want that to happen.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez. The code DOES execute if for instance you enter a type float, like Neil said.

Comment: Sure it will, but what is the next char on the stream buffer? Anyone hedging bets its a decimal ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes well done, now how to solve the issue?

Comment: My bad. I was sure that would not happen... the parser is not recognizing that as a double but as an int followed by a dot. Sorry, it was me the one that needed to check what it did.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no conversion there. If the user enters a fraction (there is no `double`), then the `>>` extraction stops at the decimal point.

http://ideone.com/azdOrO

```
int main() {
    int x;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << std::cin.rdbuf();
}

 input:

123.456

output:

.456
```

If you want to flag the existence of the decimal point as an error, you will have to do something to extract it from `cin` and detect it.

One good parsing strategy with C++ streams is to `getline` what you know you will process into an `istringstream`, call it `s`, then check that that `s.peek() == std::char_traits<char>::eof()` when you finish. If you don't use `getline` to pull the individual number, then `peek` can check whether the next character is a space (using `std::isspace`) without consuming that character from the stream.

Probably the cleanest way to check that input is finished, although it's somewhat esoteric, is to use `std::istream::sentry`.

```
if ( ! ( std::cin >> x ) || std::istream::sentry( std::cin ) ) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid or excessive input.\n";
}
```

This consumes space at the end of the input. `sentry` also provides a `noskipws` option to avoid consuming the space.

```
if ( ! ( std::cin >> x ) || std::istream::sentry( std::cin, true ) ) {
    std::cerr << "Invalid or excessive input. (No space allowed at end!)\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 checking the `rdbuf()` for additional containment that is not whitspace (empty would, by default, be ok) is a splendid work-around.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work. It ignores whitespace, I don't know if that's ok with you.

```
string s;
cin >> s;
stringstream ss(s);
int x;
if (! (ss >> x))
{
    cerr << "You didn't enter an integer." << endl;
    return -1;
}
string temp;
ss >> temp;
if (! temp.empty())
{
    cerr << "You didn't enter an integer." << endl;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: `if (! (ss >> x) || ss.peek() != stringstream::traits::eof() )` would implement my suggestion, and be more DRY.

Comment: @Potatoswatter What do you mean by DRY?

Comment: "Don't Repeat Yourself", a programming principle.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Is it correct that either condition of || may be checked first?

Comment: No, `||` sequences its operands. All side-effects of the left hand side are complete before the right-hand side begins. Unless it's overloaded, which would just be evil. (But that can't apply here.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter: But if there is white space after the integer I would still consider it valid. So I prefer `char c;if (!(ss >> x) || (ss >> c)) { /*Fail*/ }`

Comment: @LokiAstari In this example, there cannot be trailing whitespace because the stringstream was initialized by the extractor of `std::string`. Another strategy not requiring a dummy temporary and allowing whitespace would be `|| std::istream::sentry( ss )`. This is probably cleaner in every way, because you can also pass `(ss, true)` to *not* tolerate whitespace.