# How to prevent implicit conversion from char array to bool

Tags: c++, casting

```
struct Foo {
  void setBar(bool bar_) { bar = bar_; }
  bool bar;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  f.setBar("true");
}
```

The above code compiles successfully due to type conversion, even though a char array is passed where a `bool` is expected.

Is it possible to cause this code to fail compilation? (C++03 solution preferred, since the compiler at my workplace is ancient.)

I have looked at the following related questions on StackOverflow, but they don't quite address this problem. [Preventing implicit conversion in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18455755/preventing-implicit-conversion-in-c), [Why does the compiler choose bool over string for implicit typecast of L""?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316181/why-does-the-compiler-choose-bool-over-string-for-implicit-typecast-of-l)

Comment: You are **not** passing an `std::string`. You are passing a `const char[5]`. That decays to a `const char*`, which is converted to `bool`.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, sorry I realised that after posting. I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can declare a function that takes `const char*` and don't provide a definition:

```
void setBar(const char*);
```

This will make it fail at link time. You're still left will all other implicit conversion, though - from any pointer to bool, integral to bool, floats to bool...

Another option:

```
struct Foo {
  void setBar(bool bar_) {}
private:
  template<typename T>
  void setBar(T bar) {}
};
```

This way you'll get an error about it being private if you call it with anything else than `bool`.

Comment: what about `private`? can we use that?

Comment: Fail at link time is not as nice as a fail at compile time. Hence private: void setBar(const void*); without definition. In addition I recomment not to use a template (imagine you have a wrapper class around a bool).

Comment: does it prevent `setBar(42)` by chance?

Answer (score 10):

One option would be to make `setBar` a template, and allow it only to work with `bool`:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct Foo 
{
  template <typename T>
  void setBar(T bar_) 
  { 
    static_assert(std::is_same<bool,T>::value, "not bool");
    bar = bar_;         
  }
  bool bar;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  f.setBar(true);   // OK
  f.setBar("true"); // Error
  f.setBar(1);      // Error
}
```

Alternatively, you can use SFINAE with [`std::enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to the same effect, although the compiler warning might be less easy to read:

```
struct Foo 
{
   template<class T ,
            class = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<bool,T>::value>::type >
    void setBar(T bar_)
    { 
      bar = bar_;
    } 
  bool bar;
};
```

Comment: This, and you can use BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT for C++03 solution.

Comment: I would mention `std::enable_if` too.

Comment: @PetrBudnik Good idea, I added an example.

Answer (score 6):

There is a common idiom that both avoids this issue and provides other advantages. Instead of using `bool`, you can create a custom type that more clearly describes the state that it represents.

The type `bool` represents only a generic value of `true` or `false`, while in actual usage you are overloading these states to mean something more specific. Here's an example using an enum to define a new type:

```
enum Bar { ok, foobar };

struct Foo {
  void setBar(Bar bar_) { bar = bar_; }
  Bar bar;
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  f.setBar(foobar); // ok
  f.setBar("true"); // error
}
```

This still allows implicit conversion from any arithmetic or floating type. To avoid this, you can use C++11's `enum class`, or roll your own strongly-typed bool like this:

```
template<class Tag>
struct Bool { bool value; };

typedef Bool<struct BarTag> Bar;
const Bar Ok = { false };
const Bar FooBar = { true };
```