# Prevent implicit conversion of QObject* to bool : prevent 'Multiple constructor' warning

Tags: c++

I had the same issue as question [How to prevent implicit conversion from char array to bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18463937)

I have a constructor like this:

```
public:
Foo(Goo a=0, bool b=true, QObject* parent = 0);
```

I want to prevent the call

```
Foo(aGoo, aParent);
```

where `aParent` is implicitly converted to `bool`. (or any other pointer for that matter)

I've achieved this by defining

```
private:
Foo(Goo a, QObject* parent) {}
```

This provokes a 'Multiple constructors' warning which I presume is harmless since the compiler will be able to disambiguate. Nonetheless, I want to get rid of the warning. Is there any warning-less way to prevent the implicit conversion or a way to suppress that warning?

EDIT:
C++11 solutions are welcome.

Comment: I think the most obvious thing to do would be to avoid default parameter values in this case, because they're misleading. A developer might actually write `Foo(aGoo, aParent)` with the purpose of passing `static_cast<bool>(aParent)` as parameter `b`. When these things can occur, I think it's better to actually force the caller to think about what he's doing.

Comment: @GiulioFranco It would be weird that somebody used a `QObject` as a `bool` in that context. I am perfectly happy to force them to do a `static_cast` if they really want to use a `QObject` as `bool`. `b` is actually `withTimer` in practice. Nonetheless, your point is valid, maybe the default constructors have too much meaning to keep them as such.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the specification of that private constructor is not as you described, since that won't compile at all (default value for the first argument, but not the second).

Anyway, the obvious solution is not to use default values, and provide a set of constructors of the form.

```
 public:

     Foo();
     Foo(Goo);
     Foo(Goo, bool);
     Foo(Goo, bool, QObject *);

 private:

     Foo(Goo, QObject*);   // leave this undefined.
```

This will trigger a compilation error for any non-member or non-friend that attempts to invoke the private constructor.   For members and friends, the result will be a linker error.

In C++11, you can use delegating constructors to reduce code duplication.   Before C++11, use a common helper function that is called by the constructors.

The above won't stop the compiler from accepting things like

```
 Foo afoo(AGoo, (double *)0);
```

though, since almost any pointer can be implicitly converted to `bool`.   If you want to stop that, turn the private constructor into a template.

Comment: If you used the default constructors, by adding the private one, would the compiler/linker throw the error or would it pick the public, implicitly-converted constructor?

Comment: For the most part, you can't do this by allowing default values of constructor arguments.  The compiler will pick the best candidate (e.g. the constructor it can invoke without doing implicit conversions).   If there is more than one equal-best candidate, the code will be rejected as ambiguous.  But, if there is only one candidate, the compiler THEN checks access (`private`, etc) of the chosen constructor.    It will not match a public constructor preferentially over a private one.

Comment: Then, your solution with default constructors would work as expected as well, i.e. preventing the call because the best candidate it's private. But with a follow-up problem that a call to ´Foo()´ without arguments failing to compile due to ambiguity over the default public method and the private one.

Comment: You're misusing the term "default constructor" - it is something different from a constructor which has default values for some parameters   (although a constructor which has all parameters with default values can be used as a default constructor).   In any event, default values for parameters permits matches in some circumstances that are avoided by the technique I suggested.   You're missing the point:  don't use default values in this case.